# Consummation memory with QtQuick Compiler

Tags: memory, qml, qt5, ram, qt-quick

We intend to use QT5.9/QML in our commercial application, however we are worried about the memory consumption.
I read about QtQuick Compiler introduced in QT 5.8 which allows to compile QML source code into the final binary.
I wonder about the effect of QtQuick Compiler in commercial versions? did it bring a performance in memory consumption?
Is there an example of a commercial application before and after using QtQuick Compiler?